# get height width of an element from translate value of an svg element?

Tags: javascript, svg, scaling

Can any one help me to find how to calculate the height width of an svg element using its translate value.
 for Example The transform value is `rotate(55 243.7262268066406,231.7799072265625) matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)` .
I want to calculate the height width of the svg element using this translate value. Need some one help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: call element.getBBox() read off the height and width.

Comment: No I want to calculte from transform value. So how can I?

Comment: why would you need to? It's kind of hard in general.

Comment: I need to stop scaling of the svg element with a certain height and width. So how can I do it?

Comment: get the scaled bounding box (getBBox) and apply an inverse scale transform to keep the width and height to what you want it to be.

Comment: What you want is unclear?  Do you mean you want to find the horizontal and vertical size of the element **after** it have been rotated?  If so, that will depend on the element being rotated.  You should provide a [MCVE] so we can see more clearly what you are trying to do.